# How to alway show 3 digit on slotmachine jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in my slot machine,
How to make it always display 3 digit
For example, I random the number 001 - 200

I want it to show 001 from start 
and I want to display number like this 002 010 067 when it stop random

```
$('.reel-container:first').slotMachine(001).toString();

$('#gen').click(function() {
    $('.reel-container:first').slotMachine((Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1).toString());
});
```

My jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xmenzaa/mrs93b58/11/

Thanks

Comment: you have to learn regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function to generate random number

```
function randGen(){
    var  randNum = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1).toString()
    if(a.toString().length==3){
        return  randNum;
    }
    else if(a.toString().length==2){
        return "0"+ randNum;
    }
    else if(a.toString().length==1){
        return "00"+ randNum;
    }
}
```

this code generate 3 digit random number and use it in

```
$('.reel-container:first').slotMachine(randGen());
```

Comment: This is not really the way to go. Moreover, this is a question that was asked before with better answers.

Comment: Thank all now I update my fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/xmenzaa/mrs93b58/24/